# Is posible build an indoor localization system with android device inertial sensors

Tags: android, indoor-positioning-system, sensor-fusion

I'm working on an indoor positioning system and I have one doubt after failing at all my real tests:

I have done some work with android sensors values and some machine learning algorithms (with good theorical results) but in a real environement i found some problems.

My proposal was to have three phases:

1. The fist phase consist on collecting data through an android app with a map with some points. You move to real point position and save the values of sensors asociated with the coordinates of the point.
2. The second phase consist on creating a machine learning model (in this case, a classifier) to predict the user position based on sensor values at every time.
3. Then, we export the classifier to the device and get predictions of user position in real time.

The data we stored on fingerprinting phase (phase 1) was the x,y,z values of accelerometer, magnetomer and gyroscope given by the Android Sensor Manager. On a second approach, we used a median filter to filtrate noise from that values. Our problem is that the way you hold the phone change the measurements. The reason is that Android sensors values are given for device coordinate system, so sensor values are variable to phone orientation and tilt.

[Android Device Coordinate System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbNlY.png)

So, the question is:

Is posible or there is a way to build an indoor localization system (with a positioning accuracy around 2-3 meters) by only taking in account android smartphone sensors (accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetomer) using machine learning algorithms (or other algorithms) to work on real environements?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is rather broad. I would suggest reviewing the literature on 'dead reckoning as indoor location' with your favorite search engine. Also note that an accuracy of 2-3 meters means that entering either adjacent men's or women's restroom would be considered successful by your standard.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few companies that started doing fingerprinting solely based on magnetometer, but as far as I know they ended up at least mixing it with other technologies, like BLE beacons or similar.

From what I was told the problem is that magnetic fields can change drastically due to changes inside your building but also changes outside of your scope (i.e. thunderstorms).

Taking one step back I see another problem with your approach: different device models behave radically different in terms of the data their sensors provide. To make things worse, the same device may provide very different data today than it did yesterday. This is especially true for the magnetometer - at least from my experience.